# How to call a fragment method from parent activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I have a method within my fragment , I want to call that from my parent activity.How can I do that ?

I tried like this :

```
        public class FragmentClass extends Fragment{
              public void fragmethod(String data){
                  System.out.println("inside fragment"+ data);
              }
        }
```

In my activity class I called  like this:

```
FragmentClass frag = new FragmentClass ();
frag.fragmethod("hi");
```

what is the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: is it giving error the way you tried?

Comment: no, this is not giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the goal, that you want to achive. If method that you want to call is simple then it is not a good practise to create a new instance of class - you should better make method static. In another way if you will reuse that instance of fragment later your way is quite normal.

Answer (score 0):

If u having any fragment then u can use such method for fragment instance instead creating a newer one. **Static** Method also helpful to u as @bgplaya also said.

```
FragmentClass fClass=(FragmentClass) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
flass.fragMethod("Hi");
```

Comment: But will that work if he is not using persistant fragment in xml ?

Comment: No, its finding fragment in activity UI

Comment: as per the docs use of this is, Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction.

Comment: So, that is not the option for him.